# Flash Actionscript3: A layer having multiple layer masks

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, layer, mask

Is it possible to create multiple layer masks over a single layer using Actionscript3? Thanks!! I'm new to Flash.

Below is the flash effect I wanted to create with masks.

- First it starts from A and goes to B and C simultaneously.

[image]

- Then from B it goes to H and D simultaneously (the same applies to C).

[image]

- This is how the end result will look like.

[image]

*ps. I need my background to be transparent. I'm embedding it into a web page later.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite sure to say: It won't work with multiple masks on one content mc. 
Other Solutions:
a) If you're using a single color background, you could try to overlay your content with multiple movieclips of that color.
b) Try to do the animation inside a masking movieclip.

Comment: ooh yeah thanks! I never thought of that.. I was thinking of using action script. thanks! I will go with b) since I need the background to be transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is possible, the masks in flash works as Fallow:
Create 2 movie clips, set movieClip1 to be a mask, and apply it to movieClip2.
Now the movieClip2 will be seen in the region of movieClip1 only.

Now create as many masks as you need to implement your application.